# Move 3d model forwards based on rotation

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a 3d model in Xcode using SceneKit, that can rotate around itself, and i would like for it to move forwards based on rotation, for example if it is rotated 236 degrees in the z axis, it wouldn't go straight in x or y, but a bit of both so it would move forwards. Is it possible? Do i have to get any plugins?

Answer (score 0):

No plugins required.

You can do this two main ways:

1. Move the object's position relative to its rotation by changing its "transform" over time.
2. Applying force (and/or impulses) over time (or instantly) in the direction you'd like your entity to travel.

Within these two approaches are a LOT of other considerations regarding scene size, resistance, speed, immediacy, etc.